# How to fetch Nth row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL database. 
So I want to know the exact SQL query to fetch Nth row. Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
ORDER BY <somefield>
LIMIT N-1, 1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

> The SQL query below says "return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)":
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";
>
> You could also use a shorter syntax to achieve the same result:
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 15, 10";